# How to Get the Current System Time using SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, query, date, time

For tests proposes, I need to get the current system date. On Oracle we could use:

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```

On SQL SERVER, we can use:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime
```

How to query the system date time using SOQL?

Thanks.

Comment: Question title does not match accepted answer. I want to know the SOQL way too, not the APEX.

Comment: Hi @RayCheng, I just posted another answer that might give you another option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to use SOQL.  You can just create a new DateTime and set it to the current date and time like below

```
DateTime myDateTime = system.now();
```

Or if you only want the date, then

```
Date myDate = system.today();
```

Comment: More specifically, SOQL is *not* SQL. You can't create tables, add indexes, update rows, ad hoc functions, nothing. It's strictly for getting data. I wish the documentation would come right out and say that.

Comment: @sfdcfox is there a difference in using like: DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate) = :System.today() vs DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate) = TODAY? and which one is preferred? BTW I'm a big fan of your work here in SFDC SE I've sent you a LinkedIn connection request, will be honored if you let me in your circle of connections, Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman.A The preferred form would be `LastModifiedDate = TODAY`; unlike SQL, the date literals actually represent a period of time (e.g. midnight to midnight of the current date, adjusted for the user's time zone). All three forms should result in the same filter being applied.

Comment: Is there a reason why those date literals don't work in test classes? I had to replace them with the system.today() in order for my assertion to pass. ex; 
[select id from contact where DAY_ONLY (LastModifiedDate) = TODAY];
VS
[select id from contact where DAY_ONLY (LastModifiedDate) = :System.today()];
First one didn't return any records, while second one did. This is confusing me, Thanks for your help

Comment: @Bahman.A Would need to see your code. I don't see why this should make a difference. Perhaps a new question is in order, rather than flooding poor Chris' notification box?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, there is a method [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_currentTimeMillis) that returns the current time in milliseconds.

From that, you can create a new DateTime with the [DateTime.newInstance(Long)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_newInstance) method:

```
Long longtime = System.currenTimeMillis();
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(longtime);
```

Comment: One of those rare times on the SFSE where there are actually two completely different answers. ;) I prefer and use your method. This is just another way.

Comment: I use my way more often as well, but I think knowing multiple ways to do things is always helpful.  I wasn't aware you could do it this way, love learning new things.  Everyday is a school day  ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot use Apex, and need to use SOQL only, then binding is not allowed. Which means you cannot use `system.now();`

With that in mind, you can use [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), such as `YESTERDAY`, `TODAY`, `TOMORROW`, and so on.

Eg:

```
SELECT CreatedDate FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate <= TODAY
SELECT CreatedDate FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate <= YESTERDAY
```